# Time slot count in mysql table

Tags: mysql

My Table Data

**ID   Start_Time  End_Time  Count(10mins slot)?  Count(20mins slot)?**

> 1    9:00 AM         9:45 AM
>
> 2    9:10 AM       10:00 AM

I would like to find how many 10 mins.( like 9:00-9:10, 9:10-9:15 and so on..) and 20 mins. slots are available for each row

Dont know how to get this with a query, can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
       start_time,
       end_time,
       timestampdiff(MINUTE, end_time, start_time) DIV 10,
       timestampdiff(MINUTE, end_time, start_time) DIV 20
```